# Check if bot is only one mentioned

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So lemme lay out the scene: (these aren't what the code actually says but for the sake of space in the explanation, I left it short)

Person A sends this message:

`@Bot slap @membername`

Bot replies with

`@messageauthor slapped @membername`

Perfect execution and that code works just fine.

example 2

`@Bot slap @membername (with any number of args following the second mention)`
or
`@bot slap (anything can go here doesn't matter) @membername`

Bot replies with

`@messageauthor no can do`

Perfect execution and that code works just fine

example 3

`@bot slap`

Bot replies with

`@bot slapped @messageauthor because they didn't specify who to slap`

Perfect execution and that code works just fine

example 4 (and the one I'm having trouble with)

`@Bot slap membername` with no mention
or
`@Bot slap asdfg`

Bot replies with

`@messageauthor slapped @Bot`

I have tried several dozens of different ideas to get this working so that it will respond with the "no can do" response. There are 2 possible solutions that I am after.

1. get the @bot parsed out like a normal prefix (been unsuccessful as my prefix is not @, its something stupid long that no one will ever use so that all commands sent are sent with bot mentions only).
2. Somehow make this (and other commands similar) to require a second mention.
3. I'm open for other ideas as well.

Here is the code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const sarcasm = require('../assets/json/sarcasm.json'); //has variations of no can do but with major sarcasm in it

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    let user = message.mentions.users.last();

    const notargetEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#ff6600')
        .setTitle('Slap')
        .setDescription(`<@` + bot.user.id + `> slapped <@` + message.author.id + `> because they didn't specify who to slap, so it boomeranged.`)
        .setImage('my_image_gif_here.gif')
        .setFooter('Discord Server Name', 'icon_here.png')

    if (!args.length) {
        return message.channel.send(notargetEmbed);
    }

    if (args[1]) {
        return message.channel.send(`<@${message.author.id}>, ` + sarcasm[Math.floor(Math.random() * sarcasm.length)]);
    }

    const slapEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#ff6600')
        .setTitle('Slap')
        .setDescription(`<@` + message.author.id + `> slapped <@` + user.id + `> across the face!`)
        .setImage('my_image_gif_here.gif')
        .setFooter('Discord Server Name', 'icon_here.png')

    message.channel.send(slapEmbed);
};

module.exports.help = {
    name: "slap"
}
```

Comment: If the message is "@Bot slap whatever you want to put here doesn't really matter as long as there is no second mention", wouldn't the "no can do" message be sent since `args[1]` is truthy? Not sure if I'm missing something.

Comment: Because of the “ let user = message.mentions.users.last();” part, the last mentioned user is the bot so the “command” is technically valid but the response is not desired. It takes the slap command and then looks for last mentioned user and finds the bot and says “hey valid command”.

Comment: No, I was mentioning that your code will return "no can do" for the message "@Bot slap whatever you want to put...." since the second `if` condition would be `true` (`args[1]` is truthy). Why would it return "@messageauthor slapped @Bot"?

Comment: Ok I stand corrected if it had that many args then yes it would fail so lemme edit the post

Comment: Corrected the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to solve the issue is to make sure the message has a couple of mentions and that the second mention is not a bot mention.

```js
// We cannot use `message.mentions.users` to get the mentioned users
// since the order of the users returned is not as they appear in the message.
// See https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=users
const mentionedUserIds = message.content
  .match(Discord.MessageMentions.USERS_PATTERN)
  .map(id => id.slice(2, -1));
const [_, userIdToSlap] = mentionedUserIds;

if (!userIdToSlap) {
  return message.channel.send(notargetEmbed);
}

if (userIdToSlap === bot.user.id) {
  return message.channel.send(`<@${message.author.id}>, ` + sarcasm[Math.floor(Math.random() * sarcasm.length)]);
}
```

The whole code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const sarcasm = require("../assets/json/sarcasm.json");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  const mentionedUserIds = message.content
    .match(Discord.MessageMentions.USERS_PATTERN)
    .map(id => id.slice(2, -1));
  const [_, userIdToSlap] = mentionedUserIds;

  const notargetEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("#ff6600")
    .setTitle("Slap")
    .setDescription(
      `<@` +
        bot.user.id +
        `> slapped <@` +
        message.author.id +
        `> because they didn't specify who to slap, so it boomeranged.`
    )
    .setImage("my_image_gif_here.gif")
    .setFooter("Discord Server Name", "icon_here.png");

  if (!userIdToSlap) {
    return message.channel.send(notargetEmbed);
  }

  if (userIdToSlap === bot.user.id) {
    return message.channel.send(
      `<@${message.author.id}>, ` +
        sarcasm[Math.floor(Math.random() * sarcasm.length)]
    );
  }

  const slapEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("#ff6600")
    .setTitle("Slap")
    .setDescription(
      `<@` +
        message.author.id +
        `> slapped <@` +
        userIdToSlap +
        `> across the face!`
    )
    .setImage("my_image_gif_here.gif")
    .setFooter("Discord Server Name", "icon_here.png");

  message.channel.send(slapEmbed);
};
```

Note that for the input `"@Bot slap @member for something"`, the above code will slap @member. If you don't want that behavior, you can add another early return.

```js
if (args.length > 1) {
  return message.channel.send(`<@${message.author.id}> Usage: @Bot slap @member`);
}
```

Comment: @Kaspr You're welcome. Just updated my answer with a comment explaining why `message.mentions.users` shouldn't be used to get the mentioned users.

Comment: this version gave me more "not a function" errors  the previous version worked without any issues

Comment: @Kaspr Weird. Can you share the stack trace?

Comment: Not sure if this link will work but this is the post that worked. https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/85a4ec58-6bdb-41c1-803f-71dab3be87bc/view-source

Comment: @Kaspr Just updated my answer to fix the issue you mentioned. Can you try if it works?

Comment: Just noticed I mistyped something that code works